# What are the security reasons to disallow Microsoft Word uploads?

Tags: uploads, security

When I try uploading a .doc or .docx file I get this message:

> Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons

What are the security risks involved in a multisite installation (3.9.1)?

I know how to enable the feature.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.doc` files can contain executable scripts, and there is no way to make sure they are safe. The same applies to SVG and some other file types.

If WordPress would accept `.doc` files from any user with the capability `upload_files`, these files could be used to send malicious code to visitors.